# How to implement conditional cells copy in Excel Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, worksheet-function

we have a report that identifies the client number in (example) A1 "270002" and the name B1 "4K Cartage, Inc. followed by PO numbers below.
I need to take A1 & B2 and "copy" into new column J & K.
However if you see below, each client list is different....my entire worksheet is over 75000 rows.  Some Clients have 5 records, others have a few hundred.

Anything would be greatly appreciated... thanks!!!

```
270002  4K CARTAGE, INC.                            
    VCINV   2/13/2014   Suspense    Invoice $0.00   $0.01   0   KG
    VCINV   3/6/2014    Suspense    Invoice $0.00   $0.01   0   JL
    VCINV   11/26/2014  Suspense    Invoice $0.00   $0.01   0   JK
REMOVE  APCM    12/11/2014  Next Run    Credit Memo $0.00   $0.03-  0   LD
10000   A & S SERVICES GROUP, LLC                           
80000031A   VCINV   3/20/2014   03/07/14    4021225 $0.00   $927.50 0   KG
80000041A   VCINV   3/20/2014   03/07/14    4021974 $0.00   $927.50 0   KG
80000049A   VCINV   3/20/2014   03/07/14    1402049302  $0.00   $656.25 0   KG
80000065A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/13/14    4022480 $0.00   $927.50 0   JB
80000068A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/13/14    4022331 $0.00   $927.50 0   JB
80000066A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4022347 $0.00   $932.50 0   JB
80000074A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4022532 $0.00   $286.50 0   JB
80000075A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4022534 $0.00   $286.50 0   JB
80000107A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/13/14    4022740 $0.00   $586.75 0   JB
80000116A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4023306 $0.00   $585.75 0   JB
80000117A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4023308 $0.00   $585.75 0   JB
80000118A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4023307 $0.00   $585.75 0   JB
80000119A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/06/14    4023309 $0.00   $585.75 0   JB
80000120A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/13/14    4023304 $0.00   $585.75 0   JB
80000121A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/13/14    4023305 $0.00   $558.75 0   JB
80000130A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/20/14    4023651 $0.00   $585.75 0   JB
80000132A   VCINV   4/10/2014   04/20/14    4023650 $0.00   $595.75 0   JB
```

Comment: Please apply a proper format to your data sample, show your code and narrow down the question to a problematic part. Thanks and regards,

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code and where exactly you are having issues.

Answer (score 0):

With a formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("$*",$A1:$I1,0)),A1,"")
```